# convert html structure using jquery

Tags: jquery

Any idea how to convert the html structure from this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Fruit A</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>                              
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Fruit B</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>                             
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

to the following using jQuery:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Fruit A</a></h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>                             
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Fruit B</a></h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>                            
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried with [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) but no luck. Please help.

Comment: Do you know the structure before hand or are you trying to convert generated html? you could always use `$('.menu').html('//newstructure')`

Comment: i dont know what you are doing but DOM mutation is expensive do not do it, look at the templating solution savailable like jsRender https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender

Comment: could you just post the code that you used to replace the html???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways this could be done. Here's the first that came to mind:

```
var $menu = $("div.menu"),
    $ul = $menu.children("ul").detach();
$ul.children().each(function() {
    $("<div />").append($(this).children()).appendTo($menu);
});
$("div.menu > div > a").wrap("<h3 />");
```

That is, start by detaching the top level list from the menu div. Then loop through that list's li elements, appending each one's content in a new div and appending the result to the menu. Wrapping the header anchors in h3 tags seemed simpler as a separate operation at the end.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uwohih/1/edit

For more information about the jQuery methods I've used, you know [where to look](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: +1 sorry but I never saw usage of `<div />` inside `$`. Can you please provide me a link or explain how it could be used?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/izazib/6/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.menu > ul > li').each(function(){
  $(this).children('a').wrap('<h3/>');
  $(this).parent().after('<div>'+ this.innerHTML +'</div>');
}).closest('ul').remove();
```

---

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/izazib/7/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.menu > ul > li').each(function(){
  $(this).children('a').wrap('<h3/>').closest('ul').after('<div>'+ this.innerHTML +'</div>');
}).closest('ul').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I realized after the conversion, this is display in descending order. Fruit B then Fruit A.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
$(function() {
    var     menu = $('.menu'),
        newHtml = '';

    menu.children('ul li').each(function() {
        var     el = $(this);

        el.children('a').wrap('<h3></h3>');

        newHtml += '<div>'+el.html()+'</div>';
    });

    menu.html(newHtml);
});
```

Comment: it could be that children('ul li') wont work, use .children('ul').children('li').each(), then.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$('.menu > ul > li > a').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<h3></h3>');
});

var arr = [];
$('.menu ul li').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).html());
}

var newhtml = '';

for(var x in arr){
    newhtml += '<div>' + x + '</div>';
}
$('.menu').html(newhtml);
```

Comment: Note that there are anchor tags in the lower level of the menu that should not be wrapped in an h3...